# Sorting multi-variable struct on one of it's variables

Tags: c++, struct, quicksort, boolean-operations

Good morning everyone,
I'm trying to sort 3 variables connected in a struct based on the values of one of them. To make myself clear I have a structed type of variable called edge and it has 3 ints: edge.a edge.b and edge.w. I want to sort edge by the values on edge.w. I found out that to achieve that i need to use bool operators but i haven't found out how yet. This is my code:

```
struct type{
   int a,b,w;
   bool operator<(const edge&A) const{
        return w<A.w;
   };
};
type edge[6];
sort (edge);
```

sort() is included in a library and executes quicksort on the array on parenthesis.
Please help,
TY

Comment: Is this `std::sort`, or some other custom `sort` function?

Comment: Also, what is the current output you're getting and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::sort(edge, edge + 6);` , by any chance?

Comment: it is std::sort i'm not taking any output it stops compiling on sort(edge); and i havent tried sort(edge, edge+6) i will try it when i get home. Thnx btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

struct type{
   int a,b,w;
   bool operator<(const type& A) const{
        return w<A.w;
   };
};

type edge[6];

//...

std::sort( edge, edge + 6 );
```

Or

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

struct type{
   int a,b,w;
   bool operator<(const type& A) const{
        return w<A.w;
   };
};

type edge[6];

//...

std::sort( std::begin( edge ), std::end( edge ) );
```

The other approach is the following

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

struct type{
   int a,b,w;

   struct sort_by_a
   {
       bool operator ()(const type &lhs, const type &rhs ) const
       {
           return  lhs.a < rhs.a;
       }
   };
   struct sort_by_b
   {
       bool operator ()(const type &lhs, const type &rhs ) const
       {
           return  lhs.b < rhs.b;
       }
   };
   struct sort_by_w
   {
       bool operator ()(const type &lhs, const type &rhs ) const
       {
           return  lhs.w < rhs.w;
       }
   };
};

type edge[6];

//...

std::sort( std::begin( edge ), std::end( edge ), type::sort_by_a() );
//...
std::sort( std::begin( edge ), std::end( edge ), type::sort_by_b() );
//...
std::sort( std::begin( edge ), std::end( edge ), type::sort_by_w() );
```

Comment: Thnx for all the help ill try all these when i have access on my pc allthough i don't know how to use iterators :)

Comment: Thnx a lot it now not stops compiling and runs... it doesn't give any output but ill figure that out!